# Unable to create p12 from aps_production created from apple developer account using push

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, private-key, intel-xdk

I am developing an iOS app using intelXDK which uses push notification but i found one problem in achieving this.
Unable to create p12 from aps_production created from apple developer account using push.pusCSR issued from intelXDK,i could not add this certificate to my keychain showing some error like "The “System Roots” keychain cannot be modified."

Please help me on this to make this push notifications i am fresher to this platform

Comment: Hi got the answer,and push works now

Answer (score 0):

and push works now

1.created both dist and aps production cert with same csr and converted aps_production key to p12.

2.Uploaded to certificate stage in intelXDK.

3.Leave aps_production certificate tab and build the app.

it will work fine!!

Comment: okay I'm having the same issue but I'm not sure I  understand your steps? so did you uses the csr file from XDK? or did you create your own? also did you tell XDK to uses the p12 file instead of the cert file? I'm really stuck and can uses the help.. also when creating the combination file where did you get the key file? or like I said did you create the csr file outside of XDK